# Intellij authentication error after pulling branch

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, gitlab, git-pull

[image: error message] This is the error message I am getting every time I try to pull a branch from another one on Intellij. It doesn't even ask me for username and password anymore, if I click on yes I get the same error message over and over and If if click NO it says "git pull failed could not read from remote repository" 
I have tried to find a solution on similar question but none of them relate to this completely, therefore your help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is because you did not add to gitlab your intellij ssh key, and therefore you will encounter an authentication error. 
If you want to solve this you should: 
Open GitLab and go to your account settings.
Click on SSH.
Click on Add SSH Key.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Git integration should not throw such an error - all authentication errors are reported in notifications, not a dialog (unless you are using some very old version, so check what version you are on).

The error itself looks like login/password is used for authentication, but AFAIK, GitLab and GitHub require authentication via SSH-key. So make sure you have .ssh/config in place and the key configured. Also check how it works in the command line, as IntelliJ relies on the command line git client.